# Crystal recursive function resulting in a signal 11 (invalid memory access)?

Tags: tail-recursion, crystal-lang

I wanted to test recursive functions in Crystal, so I wrote something like...

```
def repeat(n)
  return if n < 0

  # Useless line just to do something
  n + 1

  repeat(n - 1)
end

repeat(100_000_000)
```

I didn't expect this to work with either `crystal recurse.cr` or `crystal build recurse.cr`, because neither one of those can optimize for tail call recursion - as expected, both resulted in stack overflows.

When I used the `--release` flag, it was totally fine - and incredibly fast.

If I did the following...

```
NUM = 100_000

def p(n)
  puts n if n % (NUM / 4) == 0
end

def recursive_repeat(n)
  return if n < 0

  p(n)

  recursive_repeat(n-1)
end

recursive_repeat(NUM)
```

... everything is fine - I don't even need to build it.

If I change to a much larger number and a non-recursive function, again it's fine...

```
NUM = 100_000_000

def p(n)
  puts n if n % (NUM / 4) == 0
end

def repeat(num)
  (0..num).each { |n| p(n) }
end

repeat(NUM)
```

If I instead use recursion, however...

```
NUM = 100_000

def p(n)
  puts n if n % (NUM / 4) == 0
end

def recursive_repeat(n)
  return if n < 0

  p(n)

  recursive_repeat(n-1)
end

recursive_repeat(NUM)
```

...I get the following output:

```
100000000

Invalid memory access (signal 11) at address 0x7fff500edff8
[4549929098] *CallStack::print_backtrace:Int32 +42
[4549928595] __crystal_sigfault_handler +35
[140735641769258] _sigtramp +26
[4549929024] *recursive_repeat<Int32>:Nil +416
[4549929028] *recursive_repeat<Int32>:Nil +420 (65519 times)
[4549926888] main +2808
```

How does using `puts` like that trigger a stack overflow - especially given that it would only write 5 lines total?

Shouldn't this still be TCO?

**Edit**

Okay, to add to the weirdness, this works...

```
NUM = 100_000_000

def p(n)
  puts n if n % (NUM / 4) == 0
end

def repeat(num)
  (0..num).each { |n| p(n) }
end

repeat(NUM)

def recursive_repeat(n)
  return if n < 0

  p(n)

  recursive_repeat(n-1)
end

recursive_repeat(NUM)
```

... but *removing* the call to `repeat(NUM)`, literally keeping every other line the same, will again result in the error.

Comment: This is probably that NUM is out range of `int`. Not an expert in this matter tho.

Comment: Good comment! I'll update using a non-recursive function to accomplish the same

Comment: That means it's a stack overflow

Comment: Apologies, I should have been clearer in my question... *Why* should that be a stack overflow? Also, I added another example about weirdness, where it works if I call the non-recursive function before it

Comment: Becouse the recursive goes below 0. It removes -1 from NUM till it reaches -. I don't think this is a good design for recursive script.

Comment: `NUM` never gets below 0, it should end *at* 0 without calling `n - 1` - besides, it hits stack overflow well before that, too, given that it only outputs `1000000` without even reaching `75_000_000`. And @asterite, stack overflow also doesn't address why it _works_ when calling the non-recursive version before it

Comment: That being said, you're probably right @IvRRimUm - there is probably a better way to design the recursion

Comment: But it does reach 0. This indeed looks weird.

Comment: Does it though? It should output `75000000`, `50000000`, and `25000000`, before it hits 0 (since it counts down from the input num - my fault for using a confusing example, given that the iterative counts up)

Comment: Crystal doesn't guarantee tail call optimization

Comment: Ah, okay.. I think that was my big misunderstanding - especially given that it optimized if I called the iterative function before the recursive one.

Comment: Which 'crystal --version' are you using? Works for my 0.27.0.

Comment: It fails to compile your "problematic code" using `Crystal 0.32.1 (2019-12-18)`